# How do I list active subscribers using Faye?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, publish-subscribe, faye

I'm using [Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/) for dispatching messages and it works well. But I want to retrieve the active connections for a given channel, and things behave a bit differently: See "[list active subscribers on a channel](http://groups.google.com/group/faye-users/browse_thread/thread/b7243a25253a579d)".

I want to show the list of current users chatting in a room. I tried to do this by intercepting the `/meta/subscribe` channel via [extensions](http://faye.jcoglan.com/ruby/extensions.html) but I'm not quite sure how to send data like the username to the server.

An intercepted message to `/meta/subscribe` looks like this:

```
{"channel"=>"/meta/subscribe", "clientId"=>"50k233b4smw8z7ux3npas1lva", "subscription"=>"/comments/new", "id"=>"2"}
```

It'd be nice to send `"username" => "foo"`.

[Monitoring](http://faye.jcoglan.com/ruby/monitoring.html) is interesting too, but again, it looks like I can't send any specific data on-subscribe.

Does anyone have experience with these kind of issues?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can attach data using a client-side extension:

```
client.addExtension({
  outgoing: function(message, callback) {
    if (message.channel === '/meta/subscribe') {
      message.ext = message.ext || {};
      message.ext.username = 'username';
    }
    callback(message);
  }
});
```

This data will then be visible to your server-side extension. However, before you implement that, read this thread: https://groups.google.com/group/faye-users/msg/53ff678bcb726fc5

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered creating a channel for periodically publishing which channel a user is currently subscribed to?  You can think of it like a heartbeat/ping with additional status information such as which user and channel they may be subscribed to.